# How can I search for videos with specific length or resolution?

Tags: windows-7, video, search

I have lost a set of videos on my computer and can't figure out how to search for them.

I know they are in 1920x1080 and another is over 3 hours.

I would like to use these parameters in a search so that I can narrow my results and get a better list. Searching on size just won't do any good and I do not remember the names.

It's in the data of the file so it should be possible. How can I search for those properties?

Comment: Related:  [How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?](https://superuser.com/q/531659/354511)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
kind:=video framewidth:1920 frameheight:1080
```

Windows 7 has very powerful built-in search. You should google for more advanced syntax.

**Update**: [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/03/mastering-windows-search-using-advanced-query-syntax.ars) has some good examples of how powerful the search has become in Windows 7.

Comment: Wow that's great :) I found more syntaxes but is there no way to use the "lenght" syntax to search for 3h+? Seems like you can specify at most "very long" which is 60 minutes which is really not that long...

Comment: Well technically it is, but you must specify it in 100ns units, e.g., 600 000 000 = 60s = 1m.

Comment: For quick reference, if you wanted videos in a certain range like from 60s to 120s you would do kind:=video length:600000000..1200000000

Comment: Do you know maybe how to do the same resolution search on windows 10? This one doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Open the folder where the files are and switch to Details view (a list with columns). Then right-click anywhere on the bar with columns and click the option "More..."

You should see a host of options to choose from. Pick the columns you want, then proceed to sort by those columns. until you find what you're looking for.