# How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-search, syntax

I've often wondered how to use Windows Search Filters. The [available documentation](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Advanced-tips-for-searching-in-Windows) is extremely limited, but its potential uses are quite large.

When I type something, the only search filters I see are "Date modified"  and "Size". Googling shows me a few other options that, sometimes, work. Every time I try to use it I'm pondering "what search filters can I use, and what options does each filter support?". Anybody any idea where to find an extensive list or how to configure Search to give me a dropdown of the possibilities?

To find something, I always go back to a command prompt. I'd like to think I can do otherwise.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to search for only folders in Windows 7 instead of folders AND files](http://superuser.com/q/116514/354511).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of "**Search Filters**", the keywords/phrase you're actually looking for is "**Advanced Query Syntax**".

As always, MSDN is the place to turn to for further help and details:

- [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28VS.85%29.aspx)

BTW, if you need a far better search utility with RegEx support, try [AstroGrep](https://superuser.com/a/512391/138343) or [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com).

Comment: AQS is said to be used by WDS, "an obsolete technology" but still used in Windows 10. AQS keywords are dependent on Windows locale: `kind`, `in`, `folder`, `date` are valid for English. Here comes the funny part. Localized syntax user guides with local keywords are machine translated, a smarter choice. [For French](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference) instead of using `sent:yesterday`, it suggests `envoyé:hier`, this may work with accents, but `mots clés:"projections de ventes »` in place of `keywords:"sales projections"` is highly suspicious...

Answer (score 7):

To search based on file system attributes (e.g., hidden, system, read-only, etc.),
use the intuitively obvious but largely undocumented `attributes` keyword. 
As discussed in [this thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/278084-how-search-explorer-files-read-only.html) on Windows 7 Help Forums, the usage is

```
attributes:numeric_attribute_code(s)
```

The file attribute values (constants) are

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY      = 1
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN        = 2
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM        = 4
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY     = 16
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE       = 32
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED     = 64 or 16384
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL        = 128
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY     = 256
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE   = 512
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 1024
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED    = 2048
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE       = 4096
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = 8192
```

> (The aforementioned Windows 7 Help Forums says that `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED` is 64,
>   but [this page about the ATTRIB command](http://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html) says that it is 16384. 
>   My testing (on Windows 7) indicates that 16384 is the correct value.)

So, for example, `attributes:1` searches for files that have the READONLY attribute set.  Only. 
This will not find files that have both the READONLY and the ARCHIVE attributes set,
use `attributes:33` for that. 
To find both (i.e., files that have the READONLY attribute set,
but not HIDDEN, SYSTEM, ENCRYPTED, COMPRESSED, or any of the other exotic, extended attributes,
regardless of the state of the ARCHIVE attribute), you could use

```
attributes:1 OR attributes:33
```

But this syntax gets unwieldy quickly.  Luckily, there is an abbreviated form:

```
attributes:(1 OR 33)
```

Conjunction/disjunction keywords (`AND` and `OR`) must be capitalized;
search filter (property) keywords like `attributes` (and `filename`, `kind`, `type`, `date`,
`datemodified`, `size`, `owner`, `datetaken`, `author`, `title`, etc.) are case-insensitive. 
By the way, if you like extra typing, you can say `system.fileattributes` instead of `attributes`.

So here are the numeric search codes for all possible searches
based on the `R`, `H`, and `A` attributes. 
(`+R` represents all read-only files, regardless of `H` and `A` status;
`+R -H` is the example from above – all non-hidden read-only files.)

> Attributes (symbolic)           Numeric `attributes:` value(s)
>      `+R`                        (1 OR 3 OR 33 OR 35)
>      `+R +H`                     (3 OR 35)
>      `+R +H +A`                  35
>      `+R +H -A`                  3
>      `+R -H`                     (1 OR 33)
>      `+R -H +A`                  33
>      `+R -H -A`                  1
>      `+R    +A`                  (33 OR 35)
>      `+R    -A`                  (1 OR 3)
>      `-R`                        (0 OR 2 OR 32 OR 34 OR 128)
>      `-R +H`                     (2 OR 34)
>      `-R +H +A`                  34
>      `-R +H -A`                  2
>      `-R -H`                     (0 OR 32 OR 128)
>      `-R -H +A`                  32
>      `-R -H -A`                  (0 OR 128)
>      `-R    +A`                  (32 OR 34)
>      `-R    -A`                  (0 OR 2 OR 128)
>         `+H`                     (2 OR 3 OR 34 OR 35)
>         `+H +A`                  (34 OR 35)
>         `+H -A`                  (2 OR 3)
>         `-H`                     (0 OR 1 OR 32 OR 33 OR 128)
>         `-H +A`                  (32 OR 33)
>         `-H -A`                  (0 OR 1 OR 128)
>            `+A`                  (32 OR 33 OR 34 OR 35)
>            `-A`                  (0 OR 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 128)

Notes:

- Any query term can be inverted by preceding it with `-` (minus). 
  For example, you can find everything *except* hidden read-only files with `-attributes:(3 OR 35)`.
- Naturally, even if you use the `attributes` keyword to search for hidden files,
  you will not find any unless you have “Show hidden files, folders, and drives” selected
  in “Folder Options”.
- Logically, files with no attributes set should have an `attributes` value of 0,
  but this seems not to be the case. 
  In my experience, they have an `attributes` value of NORMAL (128).
- To search for directories, and/or files/directories that are
  compressed, encrypted, not indexed, or have the SYSTEM attribute set,
  add the appropriate constant(s) from the first table to the values in the above table. 
  It should not be necessary to include the “128” values;
  e.g., for `-R -H +S -A`, it should be good enough to search for `4` rather than `(4 OR 132)`.
- Remember that folders that are “customized” (e.g., with a non-standard icon)
  have the READONLY attribute set.  (Customizations are stored in a hidden, system `desktop.ini` file.)
- You don’t need to use the `attributes` keyword to search for directories only
  (i.e., excluding files) if you don’t care about the other attributes; just use `type:folder`. 
  Likewise, `-type:folder` searches for files only (excluding directories). 
  Do not confuse this with `kind:folder`, which will find true file system folders,
  but also collection files like `*.CAB` and `*.ZIP`.
- Also, you can search for encrypted files and directories
  with `encryptionstatus:encrypted` or `is:encrypted`. 
  The inverse can be specified as `-encryptionstatus:encrypted`, `-is:encrypted`,
  or `encryptionstatus:unencrypted`.
- Naturally, even if you use the `attributes` keyword to search for system files,
  you will not find any unless you have “Hide protected operating system files”
  **de**selected in “Folder Options”.