# How do I add smart folders type functionality to windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, desktop

Is it possible to use a smart folder that you created on a mac and use it on a PC?

Thanks in advance for answer (s)

Comment: Welcome to SU. Can you please let us know what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Just as *Smart Folders* in OS X are saved **Spotlight** searches, similarly you can save your searches in Windows 8's **File Explorer** too:

[image: 1]

Any searches you've previously saved will be visible in the left navigation pane under **Favorites**:

[image: 2]

Note: Technically speaking they're saved as .search-ms XML files in `C:\Users\<UserName>\Searches`, and the format is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Tip: For complex searches you should check out [AQS](https://superuser.com/a/532110/138343) (another article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7)), although lack of regex support is really frustrating.

You can also use [**Libraries**](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/libraries-faq) to aggregate your files from different locations into a single place:

[image: 3]