# Search all files that are NOT one or MORE specific type/extension in a directory

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, search, find

In a folder i want all files except more than one file extension like pdf and html file. 

I have already got for single file extension which is

```
NOT *.pdf
```

But In my case I want to exclude two file extension which is html and pdf. 
What is the way to exclude more than one file extension in windows 7 or Windows *?

Comment: See also: [How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?](https://superuser.com/q/531659/150988)  Note that you could also say something like ``NOT (*.html OR *.pdf)``.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain NOT with AND to create multiple conditions.

e.g.

```
NOT *.pdf AND NOT *.html
```

This should give you the results you desire.