# List of available search prefixes

Tags: windows-10

In Windows Explorer, there is prefixes like content:xxx, file:abc.txt, but where is the complete list?

I am googling it the wrong way obviously.

There are some question about which "search filters" you can use, but since it is not obvious if those are implemented via a text prefix in the search field or not, this question is a clear complement to those.

Isnt it possible to list them using Explorer itself?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I see the available Windows Search Filters?](https://superuser.com/q/531659/150988)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I used the word "prefix" in the title of this question so it cannot be a duplicate to a question which "search filters" there are. Those could be implemented via a gui, at least it is not clear to the reader.

Comment: Potato, potahto. Different names for the same thing. On Stack Exchange (of which Super User is a part), questions don’t have to be worded identically to be duplicates; they only need to have the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is called Advanced Query Syntax (AQS). You can get the full documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference.

Comment: Beat me to it :)