# What is the keyword "type" in Windows Search advanced query syntax?

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

Windows 10 file explorer's search tools let you insert `type:` into the search box. I cannot figure out what this is, what the possible values are, and/or which files qualify for them.

- The [Advanced Query Syntax docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference) do not list `type`.
- [Perceived Types docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-perceivedtype) may possibly refer to it with the value `images`, e.g. This would match a [third-party article](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/03/mastering-windows-search-using-advanced-query-syntax/) that lists `type:image`. However, I cannot find a JPEG file using either `type:images` or `type:image`.
- [A German article](https://www.tippscout.de/windows-dateisuche-nach-name-typ-und-alter.html) says that it (or more precisely, its translation `typ`) refers to the file extension. But that does not work for me, while it does work with `ext`.

Comment: Did you try `type:=.txt` or `type:=.jpg`... I think you need to prefix the dot before the extension "type". That's just a guess that after quick testing.

Comment: Wow, check it out ["You don’t need to use the attributes keyword to search for directories only (i.e., excluding files) if you don’t care about the other attributes; just use `type:folder`.  Likewise, `-type:folder` searches for files only (excluding directories).  Do not confuse this with `kind:folder`, which will find true file system folders, but also collection files like `*.CAB` and `*.ZIP`."](https://superuser.com/questions/531659/how-can-i-see-the-available-windows-search-filters/871338#871338)... you can also use `type:script` or `type:doc` and even negate those out too.

Comment: Thanks. How did you know the `:=` syntax? I haven't seen it anywhere before.

Comment: I googled for "Windows Search advanced query examples" and then looked over various posts quickly per your inquiry, and did quick testing.

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the search syntax works differently for folders that are indexed and those that are not indexed. (I think this is very bad.)

For an indexed folder, `type:image`, `type:jpg`, `type:.jpg` and `type:=.jpg` work.

For an unindexed folder, only `type:=.jpg` works.

Thanks to [IT Thug Ninja](https://superuser.com/users/510662/it-thug-ninja) for the latter syntax.

Comment: Good to know. Looks like `type:` is meant only for searching within indexed locations. Have come across such a [situation before](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/move-copy-files-multiple-sub-folders-single-folder/#windows_search), where type:"file folder" keyword didn't work on non-indexed locations.

Answer (score 2):

The full name of the propety that appears in the `Type` column is `System.ItemTypeText`. The operative word there is "Text". You're searching the *text description* of the type (if you're searching for a specific extension, just search on the `Extension` property).

There are several query operators that are string-specific, but not widely-known, most likely becaause they are buried toward the end of [Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#query-operators).  (doesn't exactly bbubble to to the top when you search the web for "Explorer Search syntax" :D )

```
COP_VALUE_STARTSWITH    ~<
        System.FileName:~<"C++ Primer"

COP_VALUE_ENDSWITH      ~>
        System.Photo.CameraModel:~>non

COP_VALUE_CONTAINS      ~= or ~~
        System.Subject.~=round 
    or  System.Search.Autosummary:~~round

COP_VALUE_NOTCONTAINS   ~!
        System.Author:~!"sanjay"

COP_DOSWILDCARDS        ~
        System.FileName:~"Mic?osoft W*d"

COP_WORD_EQUAL          $= or $$
        System.StructuredQuery.Virtual.From:$="Sanjay Jacobs"

COP_WORD_STARTSWITH     $<
        System.Author:$<"San" 
    or  System.Filename:$<"Micro Exe"
```

Searching in non-indexed locations seems to be less forgiving regarding syntax, for instance, searching `Program Files` with `Type:"file folder"` yields `"No items match your search."`, using `type:="file folder"` yield the expected results:

[image]

But the real "magic bullet" is `COP_VALUE_CONTAINS (`**`~~`**`)`. Searching `Program Files` with `type:Configuration` yields no results, but **`~~`** matches even partial strings. `type:~~config` yields types I wasn't even aware of:

[image]

It doesn't even reqire wildcards to match partial strings. `type:=~~olde` is enough to match any type with "folder" in the description:

[image]