# Find all videos less than x seconds in length

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-search

I have a directory (`F:\video`) with many subdirectories containing various `.mp4` videos. Is there any way I can get a list of all the videos less than 15 seconds long? Preferably using the standard Windows search although I would consider installing a third party tool.

I have tried searching and listing by filesize but my videos are encoded at different bitrates, so some that are less than 15 seconds may be quite large.

If the filenames could be output to a text file that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the question at [How can I search for videos with specific length or resolution?](https://superuser.com/questions/395033/search-for-videos-with-specific-lenght-or-resolution) to add a length column and sort by it or use the advanced windows search features (it seems a little tricky trying to specify the max length).

You can enter this in the windows search box while in `F:\video`

```
kind:=video length:1..150,000,000
```

If you weren't sure of the specific length (specified in 100ns units) you could start with just entering the kind:=video and then it would search all your subfolders and you could apply the trick where you just sort on the length column.

Then just select the files from windows explorer, shift+right-click on them and select "Copy as Path" and you can paste them into notepad or a text file.

Answer (score 1):

If you select "Details" as organization in windows 7, you can then sort by length and see all the videos in order by length.

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/use-advanced-search-in-windows-7-similar-to-windows-xp/

This website will explain i think the closest you can get with windows searches. you can search videos in all the directories and then you can advanced search for length less than a minute and then go to details and sort your search results by size again.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this
`kind:video size:>900mb<2000mb length:>5min<25min`
also in length one can use `sec` instead of `min`